# What is the difference between "quote" and "estimate"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning

What is the difference betwen the words *quote* and *estimate*?

Is the difference the same in British English and American English?

Answer (score 5):

In the UK, a *quote* is the actual price to be charged for a job. An *estimate*, on the other hand, gives only an approximation of the price.

Comment: I would agree with this for US English.